# Web Based File Manager that works with Tomcat/JBoss

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jsf-2, web, file-manager

I need to manage remotely the files of a webserver without having a FTP access, I know that there are a lot of great products like http://www.filemanager.net, but I need something opensource and that can run on tomcat/JBoss (would be perfect if it was made in JSF)

Ideas?

Comment: Your question seems legit, so upvoted. You need somethng like kae's File Manager but for java or something completely written in javascript.

Comment: Have you settled for a solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently looking for the same.

/** **Update: Forget all of those below. Just tried them, none is "production ready".** **/

Until now I found the following, but havn't tested any of these yet. I will give feedback if something has satisfied my needs (maybe you will also):

- "JEExplorer", which obviously disappeared from the internet. Maybe a copy is to be found somewhere.
- JFileMan: from https://github.com/developerSid/JFileMan
- gpFinder: https://github.com/oyejorge/gpFinder, a fork of
- elFinder: https://github.com/Studio-42/elfinder (With a Java backend: https://github.com/Studio-42/elfinder-servlet)

If you have already found a tool which fits your needs let us know!